# how can I use progressbar with timer?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a array of few images. One Image is shown and after 5 seconds a new Image is shown. I want to set a animated progress bar with 5 second timer. How I do this? I found a lot of libaries but nothing with timer.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Animated, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Dimensions, Image } from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('screen');

const Test = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState(0);

  const data = [
    {
      key: '37217',
      title: 'Title 1',
      desc: 'Desc 1',
      image: 'http://192.168.0.249:3000/build/photo_1621612104216_d747ced4-b313-4687-b9ac-ab5bcd78501d.jpg'
    },
    {
      key: '37218',
      title: 'Title 2',
      desc: 'Desc 2',
      image: 'http://192.168.0.249:3000/build/photo_1621612230526_f49f2be8-6fd6-420d-b0b0-b39216418924.jpg'
    },
    {
      key: '37219',
      title: 'Title 3',
      desc: 'Desc 3',
      image: 'http://192.168.0.249:3000/build/photo_1621612230526_f49f2be8-6fd6-420d-b0b0-b39216418924.jpg'

    },
    {
      key: '37220',
      title: 'Title 4',
      desc: 'Desc 4',
      image: 'http://192.168.0.249:3000/build/photo_1621612230526_f49f2be8-6fd6-420d-b0b0-b39216418924.jpg'

    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    if(modal === true) {
      if(currentImageIndex < data.length - 1) {
      let intervalID = setInterval(() => {
        setCurrentImageIndex(prevState => prevState + 1);
      }, 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
      } else {
        setCurrentImageIndex(0);
        setModal(false);
      }
    }
  });
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
      {
        data.map((_, i) => {
          return <View key={`index${i}`}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => (setCurrentImageIndex(i),setModal(true))}>
              <Image
              style={{height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 100, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'purple'}}
              source={{uri: _.image}}
              onPress={() => (setCurrentImageIndex(i),setModal(true))}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          })
        }
      <Modal
        isVisible={modal}
        swipeDirection="down"
        onSwipeComplete={() => (setModal(false))}
        animationOut="slideOutDown"
        backdropTransitionOutTiming={0}
        style={{margin: 0, padding: 0, height: 250}}
        statusBarTranslucent
      >
        <View style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
          <Image 
            style={{height: width, width}}
            source={{uri: data[currentImageIndex].image}}  
          />
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  )
};
```

Thank you very much for your help!!!
....................................
....................................

Answer (score 0):

You can user setInterval

1. Add setinterval for image which will change image in every 5 seconds
2. Add a timer of 4 seconds as when image changes one second already gone

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/hot-celery

Example Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { ProgressBar, Colors, Card } from 'react-native-paper';

var i = 0
var seconds =0 

export default class NoApproval extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: 'orange',
      imageArray:[
        'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png',
        'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png',
        'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png',
        'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png',
        'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png'
      ],
      timerValue:0,
      progress:0
    }    
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.timer()
    this.incrementSeconds()
  }

  timer(){
    
    setInterval(()=> { 
                this.setState({
                  timerValue: this.state.timerValue+1
                },()=>{
                  if(this.state.timerValue==5){
                    this.setState({
                    timerValue: 0
                  })
                  }
                })
            }, 5000);
  }


  incrementSeconds() {
   setInterval(()=> {
                seconds = seconds +1
                
                if(seconds>5){
                  seconds=1
                }
                this.setState({
                  seconds: seconds,
                  progress: (25*seconds)/100
                })
            }, 1000);
}


render(){
  return (
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
        
          <View style={{width:300, height:300,alignItems:'center', borderWidth:1, elevation:2}}>
            
              <Image
                style={{height:300,width:300}}
                source={{uri: this.state.imageArray[this.state.timerValue]}}
              />
              
          
        </View>
        <ProgressBar progress={this.state.progress} color={Colors.red800} style={{width:300}}/>
      
    </View>
  );
  }
}
```